# How to split a column twice using Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column `{'duration': 0, 'is_incoming': False}`
I want to fetch `0` and `False`out of this. How do I split it using Python (Pandas)?

I tried - `data["additional_data"] = data["additional_data"].apply(lambda x :",".join(x.split(":")[:-1]))`

I want two columns `Duration` and `Incoming_Time`
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your column `additional_data` contains real dict / json, you can directly use the string accessor `.str[]` to get the dict values by keys, as follows:

```
data['Duration'] = data['additional_data].str['duration']
data['Incoming_Time'] = = data['additional_data].str['is_incoming']
```

If your column `additional_data` contains strings of dict (enclosing dict with a pair of single quotes or double quotes), you need to convert the string to dict first, by:

```
from ast import literal_eval

data['Duration'] = data['additional_data].map(literal_eval).str['duration']
data['Incoming_Time'] = data['additional_data].map(literal_eval).str['is_incoming']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try converting those string to actual dict:

```
from ast import literal_eval
```

Finally:

```
out=pd.DataFrame(df['additional_data'].astype(str).map(literal_eval).tolist())
```

Now if you print `out` you will get your expected output

If needed use `join()` method:

```
df=df.join(out)
```

Now if you print `df` you will get your expected result